# XML::Twig fails to install with cpan

Tags: perl, module, installation, cpan, xml-twig

I'm new to installing CGI modules. On my development machine I've use `ppm` to install modules. On my production server, I do not have ActivePerl and thus no `ppm`.

When I try to install XML::Twig with `cpan`, I get the following output:

```
CPAN: Storable loaded ok (v2.20)
Going to read '/root/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Sat, 28 Jul 2012 14:03:03 GMT
Running install for module 'XML::Twig'
CPAN: Data::Dumper loaded ok (v2.124)
'YAML' not installed, falling back to Data::Dumper and Storable to read prefs '/root/.cpan/prefs'
Running make for M/MI/MIROD/XML-Twig-3.40.tar.gz
CPAN: Digest::SHA loaded ok (v5.62)
CPAN: Compress::Zlib loaded ok (v2.037)
Checksum for /root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/M/MI/MIROD/XML-Twig-3.40.tar.gz ok
Scanning cache /root/.cpan/build for sizes
............................................................................DONE
CPAN: Archive::Tar loaded ok (v1.76)
XML-Twig-3.40/
XML-Twig-3.40/Twig.pm
XML-Twig-3.40/Twig_pm.slow
CPAN: File::Temp loaded ok (v0.22)

  CPAN.pm: Going to build M/MI/MIROD/XML-Twig-3.40.tar.gz

run 'perl Makefile.PL -y' to install all tools,
    'perl Makefile.PL -n' to skip installation
Do you want to install 'xml_pp' (XML pretty printer)? [y] Do you want to install 'xml_grep' (XML grep - grep XML files using XML::Twig's subset of XPath)? [y] Do you want to install 'xml_split' (split big XML files)? [y] Do you want to install 'xml_merge' (merge back files created by xml_split)? [y] Do you want to install 'xml_spellcheck' (spellcheck XML files skipping tags)? [y] Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Writing Makefile for XML::Twig
Could not read '/root/.cpan/build/XML-Twig-3.40-mL4ddI/META.yml'. Falling back to other methods to determine prerequisites
---- Unsatisfied dependencies detected during ----
----        MIROD/XML-Twig-3.40.tar.gz        ----
    XML::Parser [requires]
  Ignoring dependencies on modules ARRAY(0xa01ac10), ARRAY(0xa01aa90)
/usr/bin/perl speedup Twig_pm.slow > Twig.pm
/usr/bin/perl -i_bak -p filter_for_5.005 Twig.pm Twig/XPath.pm
/usr/bin/perl check_optional_modules
cp Twig.pm blib/lib/XML/Twig.pm
cp Twig/XPath.pm blib/lib/XML/Twig/XPath.pm
cp tools/xml_merge/xml_merge blib/script/xml_merge
/usr/bin/perl -MExtUtils::MY -e 'MY->fixin(shift)' -- blib/script/xml_merge
cp tools/xml_grep/xml_grep blib/script/xml_grep
/usr/bin/perl -MExtUtils::MY -e 'MY->fixin(shift)' -- blib/script/xml_grep
cp tools/xml_pp/xml_pp blib/script/xml_pp
/usr/bin/perl -MExtUtils::MY -e 'MY->fixin(shift)' -- blib/script/xml_pp
cp tools/xml_split/xml_split blib/script/xml_split
/usr/bin/perl -MExtUtils::MY -e 'MY->fixin(shift)' -- blib/script/xml_split
cp tools/xml_spellcheck/xml_spellcheck blib/script/xml_spellcheck
/usr/bin/perl -MExtUtils::MY -e 'MY->fixin(shift)' -- blib/script/xml_spellcheck
Manifying blib/man1/xml_merge.1
Manifying blib/man1/xml_grep.1
Manifying blib/man1/xml_pp.1
Manifying blib/man1/xml_split.1
Manifying blib/man1/xml_spellcheck.1
Manifying blib/man3/XML::Twig.3pm
  MIROD/XML-Twig-3.40.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make -- OK
Warning (usually harmless): 'YAML' not installed, will not store persistent state
Running make test
/usr/bin/perl speedup Twig_pm.slow > Twig.pm
/usr/bin/perl -i_bak -p filter_for_5.005 Twig.pm Twig/XPath.pm
/usr/bin/perl check_optional_modules
Skip blib/lib/XML/Twig.pm (unchanged)
Skip blib/lib/XML/Twig/XPath.pm (unchanged)
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 /usr/bin/perl "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-e" "test_harness(0, 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/*.t
t/is_field.t ........................ 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/pod.t ............................. ok
t/pod_coverage.t .................... ok
t/test1.t ........................... 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/test2.t ........................... 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/test3.t ........................... 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/test4.t ........................... 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/test5.t ........................... 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/test_3_24.t ....................... 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/test_3_26.t ....................... 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/test_3_27.t ....................... 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/test_3_30.t ....................... 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/test_3_32.t ....................... 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/test_3_35.t ....................... 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/test_3_36.t ....................... 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/test_3_38.t ....................... 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/test_3_39.t ....................... 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/test_3_40.t ....................... 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/test_additional.t ................. 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/test_attregexp_cond.t ............. 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/test_autoencoding_conversion.t .... 
Failed 2/2 subtests 
t/test_bugs_3_15.t .................. 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/test_bugs_3_18.t .................. 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/test_bugs_3_19.t .................. 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/test_bugs_3_21.t .................. 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/test_bugs_3_22.t .................. 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/test_cdata.t ...................... 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/test_class_methods.t .............. 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/test_class_selector.t ............. 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/test_comment_handler.t ............ 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/test_drop_comments.t .............. 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/test_entities.t ................... 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/test_erase.t ...................... 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/test_errors.t ..................... 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/test_even_more_coverage.t ......... 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/test_expand_external_entities.t ... 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/test_ignore_elts.t ................ 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/test_keep_atts_order.t ............ 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/test_kwalitee.t ................... ok
t/test_mark.t ....................... 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/test_memory.t ..................... 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/test_nav.t ........................ 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/test_need_3_args_open.t ........... 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/test_need_io_scalar.t ............. 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/test_need_use_bytes.t ............. 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/test_new_features_3_15.t .......... 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/test_new_features_3_16.t .......... 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/test_new_features_3_18.t .......... 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/test_new_features_3_22.t .......... 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/test_pi_handler.t ................. 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/test_pos.t ........................ 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/test_safe_encode.t ................ 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/test_simplify.t ................... 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/test_spaces.t ..................... 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/test_twig_roots.t ................. 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/test_unique_xpath.t ............... 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/test_variables.t .................. 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/test_with_lwp.t ................... 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/test_wrapped.t .................... 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/test_xml_split.t .................. 
Failed 23/59 subtests 
t/test_xml_split_g.t ................ 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
Failed 13/13 subtests 
t/test_xpath_cond.t ................. 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/tests_3_23.t ...................... 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/xmlxpath_01basic.t ................ 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/xmlxpath_02descendant.t ........... 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/xmlxpath_03star.t ................. 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/xmlxpath_04pos.t .................. 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/xmlxpath_05attrib.t ............... 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/xmlxpath_06attrib_val.t ........... 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/xmlxpath_07count.t ................ 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/xmlxpath_08name.t ................. 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/xmlxpath_09a_string_length.t ...... 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/xmlxpath_09string_length.t ........ 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/xmlxpath_10pipe.t ................. 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/xmlxpath_12axisdescendant.t ....... 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/xmlxpath_13axisparent.t ........... 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/xmlxpath_14axisancestor.t ......... 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/xmlxpath_15axisfol_sib.t .......... 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/xmlxpath_16axisprec_sib.t ......... 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/xmlxpath_17axisfollowing.t ........ 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/xmlxpath_18axispreceding.t ........ 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/xmlxpath_19axisd_or_s.t ........... 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/xmlxpath_20axisa_or_s.t ........... 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/xmlxpath_21allnodes.t ............. 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/xmlxpath_22name_select.t .......... 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/xmlxpath_23func.t ................. 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/xmlxpath_24namespaces.t ........... 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/xmlxpath_25scope.t ................ 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/xmlxpath_26predicate.t ............ 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/xmlxpath_28ancestor2.t ............ 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/xmlxpath_29desc_with_predicate.t .. 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/xmlxpath_30lang.t ................. 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/xmlxpath_additional.t ............. 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/xmlxpath_nav.t .................... 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/xmlxpath_test1.t .................. 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/xmlxpath_test_twig_roots.t ........ 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/xmlxpath_test_with_handlers.t ..... 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/xmlxpath_xpath_cond.t ............. 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/zz_dump_config.t .................. ok

Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/is_field.t                      (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/test1.t                         (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/test2.t                         (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/test3.t                         (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/test4.t                         (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/test5.t                         (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/test_3_24.t                     (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/test_3_26.t                     (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/test_3_27.t                     (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/test_3_30.t                     (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/test_3_32.t                     (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/test_3_35.t                     (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/test_3_36.t                     (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/test_3_38.t                     (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/test_3_39.t                     (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/test_3_40.t                     (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/test_additional.t               (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/test_attregexp_cond.t           (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/test_autoencoding_conversion.t  (Wstat: 0 Tests: 2 Failed: 2)
  Failed tests:  1-2
t/test_bugs_3_15.t                (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/test_bugs_3_18.t                (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/test_bugs_3_19.t                (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/test_bugs_3_21.t                (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/test_bugs_3_22.t                (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/test_cdata.t                    (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/test_class_methods.t            (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/test_class_selector.t           (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/test_comment_handler.t          (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/test_drop_comments.t            (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/test_entities.t                 (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/test_erase.t                    (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/test_errors.t                   (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/test_even_more_coverage.t       (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/test_expand_external_entities.t (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/test_ignore_elts.t              (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/test_keep_atts_order.t          (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/test_mark.t                     (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/test_memory.t                   (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/test_nav.t                      (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/test_need_3_args_open.t         (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/test_need_io_scalar.t           (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/test_need_use_bytes.t           (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/test_new_features_3_15.t        (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/test_new_features_3_16.t        (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/test_new_features_3_18.t        (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/test_new_features_3_22.t        (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/test_pi_handler.t               (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/test_pos.t                      (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/test_safe_encode.t              (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/test_simplify.t                 (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/test_spaces.t                   (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/test_twig_roots.t               (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/test_unique_xpath.t             (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/test_variables.t                (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/test_with_lwp.t                 (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/test_wrapped.t                  (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/test_xml_split.t                (Wstat: 0 Tests: 59 Failed: 23)
  Failed tests:  1-2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22
                24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36, 38, 40, 42
                44
t/test_xml_split_g.t              (Wstat: 512 Tests: 7 Failed: 7)
  Failed tests:  1-7
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 13 tests but ran 7.
t/test_xpath_cond.t               (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/tests_3_23.t                    (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/xmlxpath_01basic.t              (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/xmlxpath_02descendant.t         (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/xmlxpath_03star.t               (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/xmlxpath_04pos.t                (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/xmlxpath_05attrib.t             (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/xmlxpath_06attrib_val.t         (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/xmlxpath_07count.t              (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/xmlxpath_08name.t               (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/xmlxpath_09a_string_length.t    (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/xmlxpath_09string_length.t      (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/xmlxpath_10pipe.t               (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/xmlxpath_12axisdescendant.t     (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/xmlxpath_13axisparent.t         (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/xmlxpath_14axisancestor.t       (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/xmlxpath_15axisfol_sib.t        (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/xmlxpath_16axisprec_sib.t       (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/xmlxpath_17axisfollowing.t      (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/xmlxpath_18axispreceding.t      (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/xmlxpath_19axisd_or_s.t         (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/xmlxpath_20axisa_or_s.t         (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/xmlxpath_21allnodes.t           (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/xmlxpath_22name_select.t        (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/xmlxpath_23func.t               (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/xmlxpath_24namespaces.t         (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/xmlxpath_25scope.t              (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/xmlxpath_26predicate.t          (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/xmlxpath_28ancestor2.t          (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/xmlxpath_29desc_with_predicate.t (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/xmlxpath_30lang.t               (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/xmlxpath_additional.t           (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/xmlxpath_nav.t                  (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/xmlxpath_test1.t                (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/xmlxpath_test_twig_roots.t      (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/xmlxpath_test_with_handlers.t   (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/xmlxpath_xpath_cond.t           (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
Files=99, Tests=72,  2 wallclock secs ( 0.17 usr  0.11 sys +  1.95 cusr  0.42 csys =  2.65 CPU)
Result: FAIL
  MIROD/XML-Twig-3.40.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports MIROD/XML-Twig-3.40.tar.gz
Warning (usually harmless): 'YAML' not installed, will not store persistent state
Running make install
  make test had returned bad status, won't install without force
Failed during this command:
 MIROD/XML-Twig-3.40.tar.gz                   : make_test NO
```

Comment: "On my production server, I do not have ActivePerl and thus no ppm." — So which Perl are you using?

Answer (score 6):

It looks like there was some sort of problem with [XML::Parser](https://www.metacpan.org/module/XML::Parser), which is the Perl interface to [expat](http://expat.sourceforge.net):

```
---- Unsatisfied dependencies detected during ----
----        MIROD/XML-Twig-3.40.tar.gz        ----
    XML::Parser [requires]
  Ignoring dependencies on modules ARRAY(0xa01ac10), ARRAY(0xa01aa90)
```

Ensure that you have expat installed, install [XML::Parser](https://www.metacpan.org/module/XML::Parser), and then install [XML::Twig](https://www.metacpan.org/module/XML::Twig).

I'm a bit worried about this line, which is [CPAN::Distribution](https://www.metacpan.org/module/CPAN::Distribution) interpolating an array references that should be dereferenced:

```
Ignoring dependencies on modules ARRAY(0xa01ac10), ARRAY(0xa01aa90)
```

Which version of [CPAN] do you have? The `-v` switch should show you the program and module version:

```
% cpan -v
CPAN: File::HomeDir loaded ok (v0.99)
cpan script version 1.5701, CPAN.pm version 1.960001
```

You might need to update your CPAN tool first.

Comment: Ha Brian,Thanks for your reply. I'm running the following perl version : /usr/bin/cpan script version 1.9, CPAN.pm version 1.9402

Comment: GOT IT!!!!! Installed with the help of yum! That installation went without problems!!!!

Comment: How do you install with yum? pls mention the command @user1559932